# Generating an HTML table from an array based on dynamic key values

Tags: database, query

I'm attempting to create an reporting table for woocommerce orders based on meta_fields that change from product to product. These custom order fields are stored as rows in the woocommerce_order_items table as a named key and corresponding value, each in its own row.

This report is meant to show any of the appropriate custom field value by row, with the meta_key as the column header.

I'm able to get the following array from the db, but am struggling with how to format the results into a table, with the meta_key used as a column header, and each meta_value listed in the table appropriately.

Here's a current sample array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => cpf_first_name
            [meta_value] => John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => cpf_first_name
            [meta_value] => James
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => cpf_first_name
            [meta_value] => Jane
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => cpf_gender
            [meta_value] => Male
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => cpf_gender
            [meta_value] => Male
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => cpf_gender
            [meta_value] => Female
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => cpf_last_name
            [meta_value] => Doe
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => cpf_last_name
            [meta_value] => Doe
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => cpf_last_name
            [meta_value] => Doe
        )

)
```

Which I would like to format as:

```
|  cpf_first_name  |  cpf_last_name  |  cpf_gender  |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|  John            |  Doe            |  Male        |
|  James           |  Doe            |  Male        |
|  Jane            |  Doe            |  Female      |
|__________________|_________________|______________|
```

Comment: Hello @bshep does my answer helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tested solution-

```
// Your sample array 
$sample_array = array(
    0 => array(
        'meta_key' => 'cpf_first_name',
        'meta_value' => 'John'
    ),

    1 => array(
        'meta_key' => 'cpf_first_name',
        'meta_value' => 'James'
    ),

    2 => array(
        'meta_key' => 'cpf_first_name',
        'meta_value' => 'Jane'
    ),

    3 => array(
        'meta_key' => 'cpf_gender',
        'meta_value' => 'Male'
    ),

    4 => array(
        'meta_key' => 'cpf_gender',
        'meta_value' => 'Male'
    ),

    5 => array(
        'meta_key' => 'cpf_gender',
        'meta_value' => 'Female'
    ),

    6 => array(
        'meta_key' => 'cpf_last_name',
        'meta_value' => 'Doe'
    ),

    7 => array(
        'meta_key' => 'cpf_last_name',
        'meta_value' => 'Doe'
    ),

    8 => array(
        'meta_key' => 'cpf_last_name',
        'meta_value' => 'Doe'
    ),

);

// Here starts the real code
$headers = [];
$bodys = [];
foreach ( $sample_array as $array ) {
    if ( $array['meta_key'] == 'cpf_first_name' ){
        $bodys['cpf_first_name'][] = $array['meta_value'];
        if ( !in_array('cpf_first_name', $headers) )
            $headers[] = 'cpf_first_name';
    } elseif ( $array['meta_key'] == 'cpf_last_name' ) {
        $bodys['cpf_last_name'][] = $array['meta_value'];
        if ( !in_array('cpf_last_name', $headers) )
            $headers[] = 'cpf_last_name';
    } else {
        $bodys['cpf_gender'][] = $array['meta_value'];
        if ( !in_array('cpf_gender', $headers) )
            $headers[] = 'cpf_gender';
    }
}

$body_cpf_gender = $bodys['cpf_gender'];
unset($bodys['cpf_gender']);
$bodys['cpf_gender'] = $body_cpf_gender;
$headers= array_diff($headers, array('cpf_gender'));
array_push($headers, 'cpf_gender');
echo '<table>';
?>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <?php
        foreach ( $headers as $header ) {
            echo '<th>' . $header . '</th>';
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php for ( $i = 0; $i < count($bodys['cpf_gender']); $i++) { ?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ( $headers as $header) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $bodys[$header][$i]; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
<?php
echo '</table>';
// Here ends the real code
```

Here is the screen shot-
[image: HTML Table From ARRAY]